# Attempting to set and retrieve local storage variables in a list format

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

The objective of this code is to retrieve a random set of numbers, and the associated frame number and pass them to local storage, upon retrieval, they will be set in another location in a "frame Number" box

```js
function myFunction() {
                var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
                document.getElementById("Pins").innerHTML = x;
            }
            var clicks = 0;
            function onClick() {
                clicks += 1;
                if (clicks > 10) {
                    clicks = 0;
                }
                document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;
            };
            if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
                if (('#clicks') == 1) {
                    (localStorage.setItem("#frame1", "#clicks"))
                    document.getElementById("frame1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("#frame1");
                }
            }
            else if (('#clicks') == 2) {
                (localStorage.setItem("#frame2", "#clicks"))
                document.getElementById("frame2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("#frame2");
            }
```

```css
.framebox {
  border: 1px dashed black;
}
```

```html
    
        <button onclick="myFunction(), onClick()">Roll</button>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                Pins Hit:
            </div>
            <p id="Pins"></p>
            <div class="col-xs-12"> Frame Number</div>
            <div id="clicks"></div>
            <br />
            <h5 class="text-center">Frames</h5>
            <ul>
                <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame1" name="Frame 1"></li>
                <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame2" name="Frame 2"></li>
                <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame3" name="Frame 3"></li>
                <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame4" name="Frame 4"></li>
                <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame5" name="Frame 5"></li>
                <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame6" name="Frame 6"></li>
                <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame7" name="Frame 7"></li>
                <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame8" name="Frame 8"></li>
                <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame9" name="Frame 9"></li>
                <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame10" name="Frame 10"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

I cannot get the frames to return the correct number and score, any help is appreciated

Comment: This: `if (('#clicks') == 1)` compares the string `'#clicks'` to the number `1`, but of course they will never be equal. Are you trying to say `if (clicks == 1)` to compare the variable `clicks`?

Comment: @nnnnnn That makes sense, The objective here is to compare the current count of "#clicks" to see if the numbers match, and set the frame score based on that. Any Thoughts?

Comment: Wherever you currently have the string `"#clicks"` just use the variable `clicks` instead - similar to what you already do with `if (clicks > 10)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .framebox {
            border: 1px dashed black;
        }
    </style>


    <button onclick="myFunction();onClick()">Roll</button>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            Pins Hit:
        </div>
        <p id="Pins"></p>
        <div class="col-xs-12"> Frame Number</div>
        <div id="clicks"></div>
        <br />
        <h5 class="text-center">Frames</h5>
        <ul>
            <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame1" name="Frame 1"></li>
            <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame2" name="Frame 2"></li>
            <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame3" name="Frame 3"></li>
            <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame4" name="Frame 4"></li>
            <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame5" name="Frame 5"></li>
            <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame6" name="Frame 6"></li>
            <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame7" name="Frame 7"></li>
            <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame8" name="Frame 8"></li>
            <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame9" name="Frame 9"></li>
            <li class="framebox col-xs-1" id="frame10" name="Frame 10"></li>
        </ul>
    </div>






    <script>

        function myFunction() {
            var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            document.getElementById("Pins").innerHTML = x;
        }
        var clicks = 0;
        function onClick() {
            clicks += 1;
            if (clicks > 10) {
                clicks = 0;
            }
            document.getElementById("clicks").innerHTML = clicks;

        if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
            if ((clicks) == 1) {
                (localStorage.setItem("#frame1", clicks))
                document.getElementById("frame1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("#frame1");
            }

        else if (clicks == 2) {
            (localStorage.setItem("#frame2", clicks))
            document.getElementById("frame2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("#frame2");
        }
        }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

try above code gives output

Comment: Are we supposed to compare line by line to see what you've changed?

Comment: In question the code is out of function block and there are many syntax errors like

Comment: <button onclick="myFunction(), onClick()"> like using comma instead f semi colon etc

Comment: A comma instead of a semicolon isn't a syntax error in that context, either way will work. But it would be nicer if you could [edit] your answer to explain there rather than in comments.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting and getting String `#clicks` instead of number of clicks, Code change,

```
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (clicks == 1) {
            localStorage.setItem("#frame1", clicks);
            document.getElementById("frame1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("#frame1");
        }
    }
    else if (clicks == 2) {
        localStorage.setItem("#frame2", clicks);
        document.getElementById("frame2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("#frame2");
    }
```

Instead of storing String **#clicks** you should store **clicks** variable and use the same for comparison too.

**EDIT:** You are not able to see the number of clicks because it neither equals 1 nor 2. Put an else block as follow and see the number of clicks in console,

```
if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        if (clicks == 1) {
            localStorage.setItem("#frame1", clicks);
            document.getElementById("frame1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("#frame1");
        }
    }
    else if (clicks == 2) {
        localStorage.setItem("#frame2", clicks);
        document.getElementById("frame2").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("#frame2");
    }
else{
    console.log(clicks);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, Unfortunately it does not seem to be working correctly for retrieving.

Comment: In that case the value of clicks is neither 1 nor 2, add one more else statement, where just print the number of clicks. I'll update the answer